# Blender is undoing my progress for no reason and I don't know why

Tags: sculpting

I'm sorry for all the questions I keep asking here but I don't often use it for what I'm doing...

I'm sculpting a figure right now and I notice blender keeps undoing my progress. And no, I am NOT hitting the undo button. I will reiterate again I don't really know what I'm doing, and if you tell me about a certain function, there's a good chance I'll have no idea what you're talking about or how to get to it, or do it.

I'm probably doing SOMETHING wrong, I'm sure. But I will go through what I have done exactly.

Recently it was just a simple issue with the head. I go to my sculpting brush. I turn on Dyntopo becuase idk why, it seems to help. For instance, I am trying to make ridges in a torus and as much as I try it seems like nothing happens until I use Dyntopo. I check off smooth shading. I have most of my stuff in smooth shading so I can see what it looks like. For the head it was simply using the subtract draw brush to put holes in ears. I would go back to smooth shading. I would finish what I was doing in smooth shading so I could see what I was doing. I would switch to another body part. They're all in pieces right now. It helps me. The head is fine, until I come back, and suddenly the ear holes are gone. No undoing. They're just gone and they're gone at random.

Now, it happened again only it set me back a lot farther. I did the same thing as above. I was using subtract draw on an object. It was fine, and all the other things I'd done the same on were fine too. When I copied it I suddenly realized it had erased all that progress. It was gone on both sides, not just the one I copied.

I don't know why this keeps happening. I read something about applying modifiers and how that causes issues but I haven't done that at all. I'm just sculpting, simply; that's it. So why does this keep happening?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest stable release of Blender 2.8 and save often(use the plus sign while saving to increment a counter)

Comment: i am usig the latest version, but i don't understand what i'm doing wrong to make it randomly delete my progress

Comment: This has now crossed into really weird territory. I have never heard it affect users with an auto undo, but could you be running out of memory? Another weird one, but do you use a wireless keyboard, then update the batteries, had that my self many years ago. Is there any other software that could be running on the machine that could be causing interference? Could there be a Modifier i.e. SubSurf that is smoothing your sculpt to a high degree? or Auto Smooth? You can upload your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/